# why won't the for loop exit c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is the code:

```
pair<string,int> bank[20];
int n, money, people, temp, money_given;
string current_giver, current_receiver;
int main() {
    freopen ("readme.txt","r",stdin);
    cin >> n;
    for (int i =0; i != n; ++i){
        cin >> bank[i].first;

    }
    for (int m = 0; m != n; ++m){

        cin >> current_giver;
        cout << current_giver <<endl;
        cin >> money >> people;
        money_given = money - (money%people);
        //to subtract money
        for (auto j : bank){
            if (j.first == current_giver)
                bank[temp].second -= money_given;
            else
                ++temp;
        }

        temp = 0;
        //to add money
        for (int i =0; i < people ;++i){
            cin >>current_receiver;

            for (int j =0; j <sizeof(bank); ++j){
                if (bank[j].first == current_receiver)
                    bank[j].second += money_given/people;
            }
        }
    }
    **for (auto j : bank){
        cout << j.first << ' ' <<j.second <<endl;
    }**
```

The bolded section won't execute, but every part of the for loops above appear to work. I think the second for loop isn't being exited out of, but I'm not sure why. If there's a different cause of the problem, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you use `for (auto& j : bank)` for the loop that looks for `current_giver` you can get rid of `temp` and modify `j.second` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(bank)` does not give the number of elements in the array, but the size of the full object in terms of bytes. This will be larger than the number of elements because each element is a pair containing multiple sub-objects of at least one byte size. Therefore your loop is going out-of-bounds and causes undefined behavior.

Since C++17, you can get the number of elements in the array with (`#include<iterator>` beforehand):

```
std::size(bank)
```

or you can use `std::array` instead of a plain array (`#include<array>` beforehand). It has a member function `.size()` which will return the number of elements.

Comment: Oh ok I'll fix that, thanks. Also, the modulo operator when the input was 0 messed up that for loop - which might have caused the problem.

Comment: Or `std::size`. The `sizeof(thing)/sizeof(thing[0])` trick is error-prone and obsolete. It's a shame there's still so much material out there "teaching" it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes you are right. Changed my answer.